# How to add sum of particular column value in datagrid in WPF

Tags: wpf

I have 14 rows in my datagrid. Last column contains numeric values. The total of the last column value should be placed in the last column of the last row. How can I do this? Please tell the solution. This is my datagrid and I calculate the sum of the last column.

```
 da.Fill(dt);
object obj;
obj = dt.Compute("Sum(TotalDailyExpenses)", "");
```

I need the sum of TotalDailyExpenses value is placed below the TotalDailyExpenses column. I done the calculation part. but I don't know how to place the below the TotalDailyExpenses column...

Answer (score 0):

```
da.Fill(dt);
object obj;
obj = dt.Compute("Sum(TotalDailyExpenses)", "");

Add this value via add new row to datatable object.
dt.Rows.Add("","","",obj);
```